# Is the receiveEvent in the 'Wire Slave Receiver' Arduino-Code only called once?

Tags: arduino, i2c

I'm trying to read data from a microcontroller by reading out its i2c-interface and connecting this to my Arduino ATMega2560. If messages are received, they are printed to Serial (Arduino is on my PC-COM-Port)

My problem is, that even though i2c is sending data in a loop, only the first message is shown on my serial interface (it is received correctly!), all future messages are not send from the Arduino. I also made the Arduino just send messages in a loop to my file, that worked. So I figured it must be something with this `receiveEvent()` that is used for that purpose in the Arduino-code.

The code is from the Arduino 'slave_receiver'-example, I only changed the address.

```
// by Nicholas Zambetti <http://www.zambetti.com>

// Demonstrates use of the Wire library
// Receives data as an I2C/TWI slave device
// Refer to the "Wire Master Writer" example for use with this

// Created 29 March 2006

// This example code is in the public domain.


#include <Wire.h>

void setup() {
  Wire.begin(0x04);             // join i2c bus with address #4
  Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent); // register event
  Serial.begin(115200);           // start serial for output
}

void loop() {
  delay(1);
}

// function that executes whenever data is received from master
// this function is registered as an event, see setup()
void receiveEvent(int howMany) {
  while (1 < Wire.available()) { // loop through all but the last
    char c = Wire.read(); // receive byte as a character
    Serial.print(c);         // print the character
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, apparently I didn't really use the example from the arduino-library. The important thing here is to read one more byte after the `while (1 < Wire.available())` is exited. Then the message is "completely emptied" from the i2c buffer and the `receiveEvent` can be called again.

I think that

```
while (Wire.available()) 
  { 
    // loop through all but the last
    char c = Wire.read(); // receive byte as a character
    Serial.print(c);         // print the character
  }
```

would have been a nicer example, thats how I implemented it now and it does what it is supposed to.